# Feign is giving Exception code 0 instead of 503 when calling service unavailable

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-feign

I am using feign client to call other microservice but when the calling service is down feign should give the exception of "503 service unavailable" but it giving exceptionCode = 0  with the message "Loadbalance does not have an available server to the client".

If the service is down, I want to hit the ErrorDecoder and retry the call, but Feign is giving 0 exception codes, so it cannot reach the error decoder.
What I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your service is registered with the discovery server.
2. Check your spring properties 'spring-application-name' is equal to `feignClient` annotation's value properties

Comment: Service is registered with eureka and has same application name in feign client. The problem is when the calling service is up and running everything works fine but when i forcefully stopped the service i want 503 service unavailable on feign call but i am getting client exception with status code = 0  and message = "loadbalancer does not have available server to client"

Comment: Alright.  If you want the exception response code=503, you can create a global feign exception handler class.